# Batch script to launch an application and insert file name and then replication

Tags: windows, batch

I want to run the "mIRT-PP" program, and put in file names on the `cmd` screen.

The format of the program is as follows.
When I run the "mIRT-PP.exe", 'Control card file name:' will pop up on a `cmd` screen where I need to insert `USH_passage_BF_1.CRD`:

[image]

I need a batch file for this.
How can I do this?